# Validating complex relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-models, relationship

I am developing a Django application that helps teachers' observation
of students during lessons. I have defined models for `Lesson` and `Student`,
and a `FocusGroup` model for the students to be observed during a given `Lesson`,
The `FocusGroup` object has fields for observing `Student` behavior uring a `Lesson`.
A sample of students are observed during the said `Lesson`,
and the observations are to be registered in `FocusGroup` fields.
As part of the teacher’s preparation for the given `Lesson`,
he assigns that `Lesson` to a number of
`FocusGroup` instances (representing `Student`s)
Now, the application needs to ensure, that the
same `Student` is assigned at most once to a given `Lesson`.
I do this in my template already,
but I want to assure uniqueness on the server side as well.

The diagram should illustrate this:
[image: UML diagram of Lesson, FocusGroup and Student relationships]
My question is how I should assure the `Lesson` is assigned the same
`Student` at most once.

Should I do that in the `FocusGroup` model or in the receiving View?
And how should I get this relationship assured safely in Django?

My present implementation checks for `FocusGroup`-`Lesson` uniqueness,
but with new `FocusGroup` instances generated, there is a chance that the same
`Student` is represented by more than one of the `FocusGroup` instances
assigned to that `Lesson`.

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.functions      import Random
from django.db                       import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.db.models.fields         import AutoField, BooleanField, CharField, DateField, DateTimeField, IntegerField, TextField, URLField

class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, 
        default=uuid.uuid4, 
        editable=False
    )
    name = models.CharField()

class Lesson(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    afholdt = DateField(help_text='Planlagt / faktisk dato for modulet')

class FocusGroup(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(
        'Lesson', 
        models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True, 
        null=True, 
    )
    rand_rank = models.FloatField( # Used to randomize sampling of Students
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)],
        default=Random(),
        editable=False,
        null=False
    )
    score    = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: The models seems to suggest there can be only 1 student per focus group.

Comment: @bdbd: Correct, so that check will happen wit no problems. The problem arises when I have assigned the same student to several FocusGroup instances -- validation will not catch that identity. I.e. my model as is does not validate for the ID of the related object Student (of another FocusGroup instance already assigned with this Lecture) when assigning Lecture to FocusGroup.

Comment: In that case I think using [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) be enough. So: `UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'lesson'], name='unique_lesson_to_student')` added on `FocusGroup`. This will ensure a lesson is assigned to a student only once, regardless of which focus group.

Comment: @bdbd Looks good. Result here for feedback when I have tried it out.

Comment: I implemented the statement recommened by @bdbd. Then, after running `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `... migrate` on the application, I actually get the expected reaction (app throws the `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: myapp_focusgroup.student_id, myapp_focusgroup.lecture_id` error). Make that an answer, and I shall accept it.

Comment: Sounds good! Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it should be enough to define a [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) to ensure that students will only be assigned a lesson once, regardless of focus group, so:

```py
class FocusGroup(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'lesson'], name='unique_lesson_to_student')
        ]
```